# Window dragging with arrow icon

Tags: wpf, drag-and-drop, window

I want to drag my window with arrow icon from right side bottom corner and its working fine, but it's shrinking fully like window disappearing fully but i want up to some extent only user able to shrink the window so any one help how can I do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am understanding you correctly you need to set the [`MinHeight`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.minheight.aspx) and [`MinWidth`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.minwidth.aspx) Properties on your Main Form.

i.e

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" MinHeight="200" MinWidth="200">
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```